# Shell command output in statusline: Functions and macros

Tags: macros, vifm

I wanted to put the selected file owner and current directory permissions (in the form `drwxrwxrwx`) in the form `Owner:{owner}|Updir:{perms}`.

It turned out to be tricky, involving macros and internal functions, so I am sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `vifmrc`:

```
set statusline=Owner:%u\|Updir:"%{system('stat --printf=%A '.expand('%d'))}"
```

- `%u` is a macro that expands to the owner of the selected file, as described under the "statusline" section of the [help file](https://vifm.info/manual.shtml).
- `\|` is the pipe character. It needs to be escaped because Vifm treats the unescaped form as command concatenation.

Now for the tricky bit: To retrieve the permissions in the required form, the `stat --printf=%A {directory}` should be evaluated by the shell. So,

1. First, the evaluate expression syntax `%{expr}` needs to be used and enclosed in quotes, since the result should be a string.
2. Then, use `system({command})` to invoke the command under the system shell.
3. The command to pass to the shell is the result of concatenating `stat --printf=%A`  (note the trailing space) with the directory name.
   The directory name is retrieved with the Vifm macro `%d`, which needs to be expanded with `expand({macro})`, and the concatenation is done by the `.` character.